# error compilacion al hacer un menú en el main

Tags: c++

acabo de compilar el siguiente código  y me sale un error que no lo entiendo, el código es este:

Sinceramente no acabo de entender que me quiere decir porque  las llamadas a funciones se hacen así.

me sale el siguiente error:

```
1   9       [Warning] #pragma once in main file


    In function 'int main()':
36  20      [Error] expected primary-expression before 'void'

39  26      [Error] expected primary-expression before 'void'
```

los errores se refieren a estas lineas de codigo:

```
objeto.inversa(void);

objeto.concatenacion(void);
```

este es el codigo en cuestion:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include "operations.hpp"
#include<string>
using namespace std;
// el menu que visualizara el usuario

int main(void){


string cadena1;
string cadena2;
char opcion;
cout<<" Si quiere especificar la cadena vacia del lenguaje, ponga & , tampoco olvide las llaves para señalar el inicio y fin del lenguaje "<<endl;
cout<< "escriba  los conjuntos del lenguaje  "<<endl;
cin>>cadena1;

operaciones objeto(cadena1);

    do {
        cout<<" calculadora de lenguajes regulares "<< endl;

        cout<<" 1.Inversa  "<<endl;
        cout<<" 2.Concatenacion  "<<endl;
        cout<<" 3.Union  "<<endl;
        cout<<" 4.Interseccion "<<endl;
        cout<<" 5.Diferencia "<<endl;
        cout<<" 6.Sublenguaje "<<endl;
        cout<<" 7.Finalizar el programa "<<endl;
        cout<<" Elija una opcion  "<<endl;
        cin>> opcion;


        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                objeto.inversa(void);
                break;
            case 2:
                objeto.concatenacion(void);
                break;
```

este es el codigo de inversa y concatenacion , que esta en otro fichero, ese fichero fue compilado y no da errores, en cambio el main sí.

```
void inversa(){ //devuelves un tipo de datos
    set<string>::iterator it; // iterator es una clase que en funcion de la clase que la llama, crea un iterador que se adecue a esa clase, set su caracteristica es la posicion es el valor
    char temporal;
    char ite;
    char iter;

    for(it=lenguaje.begin(); it!=lenguaje.end();it++){ //con sets hay que utilizar iteradores, set es el conjunto, no se pueden usar []
          //end es posicion de memoria,tiene direcciones que si las divides te da otras posiciones de memoria
        int i=0;
        int j=((*it).size() - 1); // el size del string que hay en esa posicion
        //string tiene sobrecargado el operador corchete
        for(ite=(*it)[i], iter=((*it)[j]); i<((*it).size()/2);i++,j--){ // ten en cuenta que it contiene cadena de caracteres, no puedes tratar iterador como vector, saber posicion intermedia

            temporal=ite; //recuerda que son punteros de it, en el for estas apuntando a begin() y end() con ite e iter repectivamente
            ite=iter;
            iter=temporal;

        }

    }

    write(lenguaje,cout);
}

void concatenacion (operaciones lenguaje2){ //no puedes tener dos objetos invocantes, uno lo pasas por parametros
    set<string>::iterator it1;
    set<string>::iterator it2;
    char it3;
    string resultado;
    set<string> result;

    for(it1=lenguaje.begin();it1!=lenguaje.end();it1++){
        for(it2=lenguaje2.lenguaje.begin();it2!=lenguaje2.lenguaje.end();it2++){
            if((*it1)== "&"){ // & cadena vacio si es un elemento, lo reconoce como  un string 
                resultado=(*it2);
            }
            else{
                resultado= (*it1);
                if((*it2)!="&"){
                    int i=0;
                    for(it3=(*it2)[i];i<(*it2).size();i++){ //char coge los numeros como si fuesen char recuerda puedes quitar it3=(*it2)[i] y poner i=0 solo que vas a meter en el pus back *(it2)(i) 
                        resultado.push_back(it3); //no estoy utilizando it3 como iterador, por eso quito el asterisco
                    }
                }
            }
            result.insert(resultado);

        }

    }

    write(result,cout);
}
```

se agradece vuestra ayuda. Gracias

Comment: olvidate de los `std::iterators` son C++ antiguo, usa la palabra `auto` es mejor y mucho mas legible

Comment: @RenatoA. Hola, me podrias decir que significan esos errores que me salen al compilar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no acabo de entender que me quiere decir porque las llamadas a funciones se hacen así.

```
objeto.inversa(void);
objeto.concatenacion(void);
```

Lamento mucho informarte de que no, las llamadas a funciones no se hacen así. Te sobra el `void`.

```
objeto.inversa( );
objeto.concatenacion( );
```

Adicionalmente, fíjate que has declarado

```
void concatenacion (operaciones lenguaje2)
```

Esa función **requiere** ser llamada con un parámetro, y tu no lo estás pasando ninguno.